# How to mock calling to base class with gmock

Tags: inheritance, mocking, googlemock

Given 2 classes like below:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void doSmt(void);
}

class Derived : public Base
{
    void doSmt(void) { Base::doSmt(); }
}
```

Class I need to test is `Derived`. But I don't want to go deeper in `Base`, I just want to check that a call to Base is called inside `doSmt()`

Something like this:

```
TEST_F(Derived, DoSmt)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(Base, doSmt()).Times(1);
    testedInstance.doSmt();
}
```

Because I already have test for Base, and Base was inherited by 2 classes.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was assigned to write unittest for "evil" design beside with gmock. From the beginning it's harder than I though, but I also have my own solution for this.

It simple than I though (again :D)

1.Insert into Base class header any mock needed. Or you can create a new one and specify its path include.

```
class Base
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(mock_doSmt, void());
    void doSmt(void);
}
```

2.For calling to Base mock method, just create `BaseStub.cpp`

This source purpose for mocking only. So that, you have to compile & link with `BaseStub.cpp` instead of  `Base.cpp`

```
void Base::doSmt(void) { mock_doSmt(); }
```

3.When test

```
EXPECT_CALL(*reinterpret_cast<Base*>(&derivedInstance), mock_doSmt()).Times(1);
```

**mock_doSmt** instead of **doSmt**

This way can resolve Singleton too. Create SingletonStub like above, and in SetUp() just `singletonInstance = Singleton::getInstance();`

Remember: This way, you have 2 source and 2 header.

When facing this fool, I recognized that should use `#include <...>` instead of `#include "..."`

Cause to when you specify include dir, `#include <...>` will let you more control.

And another important I'd like to share is

*Do not abstract so much your OOP. Cause It will take you (or your colleague) into a very big troubles after that. Don't inherit more than 2 level, just 1 interface and 1 inherit.*

Comment: Interesting solution. I've done a #ifdef GTEST to ensure that production code does not contain "test stuff". +1

Answer (score 0):

As written, there's no (straight-forward) way to mock the explicit call to `Base::doSmt()`. It's hard to make a judgement call without knowing the context of how the `Base` class is used, but my guess is that you would be better served by using composition instead of inheritance to re-use the functionality provided by `Base`. This would make testing classes dependent on `Base` much easier, as you could simply inject a mock `Base` class into `Derived` and verify that `Base` is called appropriately.